# SQL Join Multiple Tables and get the first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, join

I have a database where there are customers, phones, and addresses. Customers can have multiple phones and addresses and each phone and address record has a corresponding CustID. I'm trying to join these three tables and grab one phone and one address per customer, but cannot get this to work. The query returns one phone number per customer, but still return multiple addresses.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT customer_set.ID, 
       phone_set.cphone, 
       customer_set.Name, 
       address_set.Number, 
       address_set.Street
FROM (
   SELECT ID, Name FROM CUSTOMER
) AS customer_set
  LEFT JOIN PHONE AS phone_set
             ON phone_set.CustID = (SELECT TOP 1 CustID 
                                    FROM PHONE 
                                    WHERE CustID = customer_set.ID 
                                    ORDER BY IsPrimary DESC)

LEFT JOIN ADDRESS AS address_set
       ON address_set.CustID = (SELECT TOP 1 CustID 
                                FROM ADDRESS 
                                WHERE CustID = customer_set.ID 
                                ORDER BY IsPrimary DESC)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `FROM (
   SELECT ID, Name FROM CUSTOMER
) AS customer_set` can be simplified to `from customer as customer_set`

Comment: Can you have multiple phone numbers with `isPrimary = true`?

Comment: This need to run on MSSQL and SQLite.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, there are business rules in place to prevent this, but there is absolutely a possibility that there can be multiple IsPrimary=true per customer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT
  data.ID,
  data.cphone,
  data.Name,
  data.Number,
  data.Street
FROM (SELECT
  customer_set.ID,
  phone_set.cphone,
  customer_set.Name,
  address_set.Number,
  address_set.Street,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_set.ID ORDER BY customer_set.Name ASC) AS RowNum

FROM customer_set
LEFT OUTER JOIN PHONE
  ON PHONE.CustID = customer_set.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS
  ON ADDRESS.CustID = customer_set.ID) AS data
WHERE data.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: This works well for MSSQL, however this needs to work on SQLite as well.